# How to force a Test task to run when the task is defined within a task rule?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I understand that you can force a Test task to run by adding something like below to `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType( Test ) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to apply to a Test task that is defined inside a task rule. Specifically, I have a task rule as below:

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: single<ID>: Run single test.") { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith("single")) {
        String pattern = taskName - 'single'
        task(taskName, type: Test ) {
            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
            include pattern
        }
    }
}
```

However, even though I have the first block above in my `build.gradle`, the task rule always finishes without doing anything. Below is an example output:

```
$ gradle cleanTest singleBuildInfoScenario000001
:cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:singleBuildInfoScenario000001 UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.868 secs
```

So, how can I have the corresponding test to run when I use the task rule?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `singleBuildInfoScenario000001` is up-to-date because it doesn't have any tests to run. (Running with `--info` might give more information.) Looks like the task is missing some configuration information such as `classpath` and `testClassesDir`. For an example on how to configure a `Test` task from scratch, see `samples/java/withIntegrationTests` in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I double checked with other dummy JUnit test cases. The same thing occurred. (BuildInfoScenario000001 is a Cucumber test, so that might make things a bit complicated.) Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: What is it that you checked? The `Test` task configuration given above is definitely insufficient. So far, I don't have any reason to believe that this is a Gradle bug.

Comment: .@Peter: I checked again about the settings. It turns out that the first statement of your answer captured the problem: the task doesn't have any tests to run. I changed the pattern to `'**/*' + pattern + '*'`. Then every thing is working as expected. Thank you very much.